# Display alternative images / tiles where tile display fails (D3 Geo Tiles)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to amend Mike Bostock's D3 geo tiles application such that an alternative image / tile-set is displayed where no tiles can be found (e.g. zoom level is too high). This would provided added flexibility to the script.

My solution nearly works but I cannot pass on the tile scale / transform (d) to my workaround function. Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/samfcgyw/), and the below is the bit of code where I try to display alternative images where there tiles fail to load:

```
 image.enter().append("image")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d[0] * 256; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d[1] * 256; })
      .attr("width", 256)
      .attr("height", 256);

    // create a test image
    var imgTest = new Image();

    // if it loads successfully add it to the svg image
    imgTest.onload = function(d) {
      image.data(tiles, function(d) { return d})
             .attr("xlink:href", function(d){return imgTest.src});
    }
    // if it fails test another image
    imgTest.onerror = function() {
      imgTest.src = "https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff.png&text=An+Image!"
    }
    // this will (potentially) fail
    imgTest.src = "https://" + "abc"[d[1] % 3] + ".tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.natural-earth-2/" + d[2] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[1] + ".png";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well nobody stepped in to answer my question. I nonetheless identified an alternative way to achieve what I needed (i.e. get rid of those ghastly broken link icons). It's ridiculously simple ... but couldn't find this anywhere, and it works with D3.

```
.attr("onerror", "this.style.display='none'")
```

Here's the line of code in context:

```
image.enter().append("image")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "https://" + "abc"[d[1] % 3] + ".tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.natural-earth-2/" + d[2] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[1] + ".png"; })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d[0] * 256; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d[1] * 256; })
      .attr("onerror", "this.style.display='none'")
      .attr("width", 256)
      .attr("height", 256);
```